# Gathering data from file returns an empty string in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to return data from file with a set of sentences and a limiter. Here's the example of my `inputs.txt`.

```
1
The dog
The cat
The mouse
The mouse
The cow
The boat
```

With the first line as a limiter I'm trying to get only the first sentence but it returns an empty string. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class dep {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("inputs.txt"));
        int lim = s.nextInt();

        while(s.hasNextLine() && lim != count) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            count++;      
        }    
            System.out.print("==DONE LOOPING==");
    }
}
```

`Output:`

```
<empty_string>
==DONE LOOPING==
```

`Expected output`

```
The dog
==DONE LOOPING==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.nextInt()` just reads the next int, leaving the rest of the line for later.

So your first pass of the loop reads just the newline after the 1.

To test this, change you first line to

```
1 foo
```

and see what your program outputs.

To fix, do a `nextLine()` after `nextInt()`.

Comment: This error haunts me for weeks but needs a line to fix. I'm so dumb. Hahaha thanks Bob! Btw

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` doesn't consume the newline character, and `nextLine()` consumes everything up to it. You need another `nextLine()` to consume that newline character before you start looping:

```
int lim = s.nextInt();
s.nextLine(); // Consume the newline after the limit

while(s.hasNextLine() && lim != count) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    count++;      
}
```